# Unable to insert data from post array in MySQL

Tags: php, post, mysqli, insert-into

As in topic, I'm beginner in programming but I've recently created some code that looks ok for me for now(yeah some things are messed up but I' going to work on it), so I have ordinary registration form looking like this:

```
    include 'modules/translator.php';
include 'includes/database.php';
include 'includes/header.php';

echo '<div id="regbox">
         <ul>
         <li><a href="registration.php" class="rbutton" onclick="return regboxr();">'. $LANG['REGISTER'] .'</a></li>
         <li><a href="login.php" class="sbutton" onclick="return regboxs();">'. $LANG['SIGNIN'] .'</a></li>
         </ul>
         <form action="registration_action.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
         <div class="input-w"><label for="name"><img src="theme/original/images/user.png"/></label><input type="text" name="regname" placeholder="'. $LANG['NAME'] .'"class="input"></div>
         <div class="input-w"><label for="surname"><img src="theme/original/images/surname.png"/></label><input type="text" name="regsurname" placeholder="'. $LANG['SURNAME'] .'"class="input"></div>
         <div class="input-w"><label for="nickname"><img src="theme/original/images/nick.png"/></label><input type="text" name="regnickname" placeholder="'. $LANG['NICKNAME'] .'"class="input"></div>
         <div class="input-w"><label for="email"><img src="theme/original/images/email.png"/></label><input type="text" name="regemail" placeholder="'. $LANG['EMAIL'] .'"class="input"></div>
         <div class="input-w"><label for="pass"><img src="theme/original/images/password.png"/></label><input type="password" name="regpass" placeholder="'. $LANG['PASSWORD'] .'"class="input"></div>
         <div class="input-w"><label for="rpass"><img src="theme/original/images/rpassword.png"/></label><input type="password" name="regrpass" placeholder="'. $LANG['RPASSWORD'] .'"class="input"></div>
         <div class="registerholder"><input type="submit" class="register" value="'.$LANG['REGISTER_SUBMIT'].'"></div>
         </form>
         </div>';

include 'includes/footer.php';
```

And this is file which checks for errors(if format of e-mail is proper for example), and if no errors should insert data into database:

```
/*Include translating module,database settings,
functions needed to prepare data from form, 
to insert them into database and user interface header.*/

include 'modules/translator.php';
include 'includes/database.php';
include 'includes/functions.php';
include 'includes/header.php';

/*Variables including data from registration.php form.*/

$name=$_POST[regname];
$surname=$_POST[regsurname];
$nickname=$_POST[regnickname];
$email=$_POST[regemail];
$password=$_POST[regpass];
$rpassword=$_POST[regrpass];

/*Variable used to count errors occured during registration process.*/

$errorcounter=0;

/*Variables used to display errors that occured during registration process.*/

$errornameset='';
$errorname='';
$errornamelength='';
$errorsurnameset='';
$errorsurname='';
$errorsurnamelength='';
$errornicknameset='';
$errornickname='';
$errornicknamelength='';
$erroremailset='';
$erroremail='';
$errorpasswordset='';
$errorpassword='';
$errorpasswordlength='';
$errorpasswordcomparison='';
$registrationset1='';
$registrationset2='';
$errordbconnection='';


if(empty($name)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errornameset='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_NAME_SET'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(!preg_match('/^[A-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-ząćęłńóśźż]{2,}$/', $name)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorname='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_NAME_CHAR'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(strlen($name)<3 || strlen($name)>16){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errornamelength='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_NAME_LENGTH'] . '<br>';

}

if(empty($surname)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorsurnameset='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_SURNAME_SET'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(!preg_match('/^[A-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ][a-ząćęłńóśźż]{2,}$/', $surname)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorsurname='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_SURNAME_CHAR'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(strlen($surname)<3 || strlen($surname)>32){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorsurnamelength='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_SURNAME_LENGTH'] . '<br>';

}

if(empty($nickname)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errornicknameset='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_NICKNAME_SET'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,}$/', $nickname)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errornickname='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_NICKNAME_CHAR'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(strlen($nickname)<3 || strlen($nickname)>12){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errornicknamelength='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_NICKNAME_LENGTH'] . '<br>';

}

if(empty($email)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $erroremailset='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_EMAIL_SET'] . '<br>';

     }
elseif(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_]{2,}\@[A-Za-z0-9\.\-\_]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/', $email)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $erroremail='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_EMAIL_CHAR'] . '<br>';

}

if(empty($password) || empty($rpassword)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorpasswordset='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_PASSWORD_SET'] . '<br>';

     }
elseif(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-_@#]{6,}$/', $password)){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorpassword='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_PASSWORD_CHAR'] . '<br>';

}
elseif(strlen($password)<6 || strlen($password)>32){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorpasswordlength='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_PASSWORD_LENGTH'] . '<br>';

     }
elseif($password !== $rpassword){

     $errorcounter++;
     $errorpasswordcomparison='&#8226' . $LANG['ERR_REG_PASSWORD_COMPARISON'] . '<br>';

}

if($errorcounter==1){

     echo '<div class="warning"><div class="wimg"><img src="theme/original/images/warning.png"/></div><div class="wheaderc"><span class="wheader">'. $LANG['ERR_REG_COUNT_MESSAGE'] . $errorcounter . $LANG['ERR_REG_COUNT_1'] . '</span></div><div class="wspacer"></div><div class="errors">' .
             $errornameset . 
             $errorname . 
             $errornamelength . 
             $errorsurnameset . 
             $errorsurname . 
             $errorsurnamelength . 
             $errornicknameset . 
             $errornickname . 
             $errornicknamelength . 
             $erroremailset . 
             $erroremail . 
             $errorpasswordset . 
             $errorpassword . 
             $errorpasswordlength . 
             $errorpasswordcomparison . 
             '</div><div class="aspacer"></div><a href="registration.php" class="reglink">' . $LANG['REG_FIX'] . '</a></div>';

}
elseif($errorcounter>1 && $errorcounter<5){

     echo '<div class="warning"><div class="wimg"><img src="theme/original/images/warning.png"/></div><div class="wheaderc"><span class="wheader">'. $LANG['ERR_REG_COUNT_MESSAGE'] . $errorcounter . $LANG['ERR_REG_COUNT_1_5'] . '</span></div><div class="wspacer"></div><div class="errors">' .
             $errornameset . 
             $errorname . 
             $errornamelength . 
             $errorsurnameset . 
             $errorsurname . 
             $errorsurnamelength . 
             $errornicknameset . 
             $errornickname . 
             $errornicknamelength . 
             $erroremailset . 
             $erroremail . 
             $errorpasswordset . 
             $errorpassword . 
             $errorpasswordlength . 
             $errorpasswordcomparison . 
             '</div><div class="aspacer"></div><a href="registration.php" class="reglink">' . $LANG['REG_FIX'] . '</a></div>';

}
elseif($errorcounter>4){

     echo '<div class="warning"><div class="wimg"><img src="theme/original/images/warning.png"/></div><div class="wheaderc"><span class="wheader">'. $LANG['ERR_REG_COUNT_MESSAGE'] . $errorcounter . $LANG['ERR_REG_COUNT_4'] . '</span></div><div class="wspacer"></div><div class="errors">' .
             $errornameset . 
             $errorname . 
             $errornamelength . 
             $errorsurnameset . 
             $errorsurname . 
             $errorsurnamelength . 
             $errornicknameset . 
             $errornickname . 
             $errornicknamelength . 
             $erroremailset . 
             $erroremail . 
             $errorpasswordset . 
             $errorpassword . 
             $errorpasswordlength . 
             $errorpasswordcomparison . 
             '</div><div class="aspacer"></div><a href="registration.php" class="reglink">' . $LANG['REG_FIX'] . '</a></div>';

}
else{

     $group=1;
     $token=md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
     $connection=mysqli_connect(db_server, db_user, db_password, db_name);
     $regquery="INSERT INTO users (name, surname, nickname, e-mail, password, group, token) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$surname."', '".$nickname."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$group."', '".$token."')";

     if(mysqli_query($connection, $regquery)){

         echo '<div class="alert"><div class="wimg"><img src="theme/original/images/alert.png"/></div><div class="aheaderc"><span class="aheader">'. $LANG['REG_COMPLETED_HEADER'] .'</span></div><div class="wspacer"></div><div class="alertm">' .
             $registrationset1=$LANG['REG_COMPLETED_MESSAGE_1'] . $email . "." . $registrationset2=$LANG['REG_COMPLETED_MESSAGE_2'] .
             '</div><div class="aspacer"></div><a href="index.php" class="mainlink">' . $LANG['REG_MAIN'] . '</a></div>';

         mysqli_close($connection);

     }
     else{

         echo '<div class="warning"><div class="wimg"><img src="theme/original/images/warning.png"/></div><div class="wheaderc"><span class="wheader">'. $LANG['DB_ERR_HEADER'] . '</span></div><div class="wspacer"></div><div class="errors">' .
             $errordbconnection = $LANG['DB_ERR_CONNECTION'] .
             '</div><div class="dbspacer"></div><a href="registration.php" class="reglink">' . $LANG['REG_FIX'] . '</a></div>';

     }

}

include 'includes/footer.php';
```

And that's it.As addition I can say that i checked if connection in this file works properly and test was positive.One more thing I guess, in div with warning class is everything negative and in div with alert class is everything positive.My script prints negative div which means that no records inserted into DB(I checked that in phpmyadmin-no records).I tried everything including rebuilding my code but this doesn't works.MySQL Improved is available in my hosting services.Any ideas dear programmers?Thank You for Your time and waiting in hope for good answers. :)

Comment: Waaaaay too much code to try and guess what the problem might be, and you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: You should try this : `$name=$_POST['regname'];`. (and same thing for all your POST variables)

Comment: Marc B yeah I know, but as I said i just finished to learn PHP and this is just other try to practice earned knowledge.

Raphaël Gonçalves, sorry but Your suggestion hasn't fixed my problem, without that quotes data which I want to insert are available too, anyway after changes You advice me nothing changes. :(

Comment: Turn on error reporting, and test it in parts.  If you can't insert records, hard code values into your variables rather than taking the post vars, and if it still doesn't work you know it's your insertion query.  If that's the case, then echo out your query.  In small parts you'll be able to eliminate some possibilities and identify the issues and fix them one at a time and then put all your working parts back together.

Comment: Learn a framework like Symphony, Laravel or Zend Framework. This is a bad programming example and you are on the wrong way. (No offense, just a friendly advice)

Comment: I'm not going to learn framework for now, I just want to understand what's bad with that what i recently created.Please help me, I know about frameworks some things because my book touched that topic but not too deep.Maybe somebody will give me idea.Thanks for all replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string you're using

```
INSERT INTO users (name, surname, nickname, e-mail, password, group, token) VALUES ...
```

won't work in MySQL as it is. The reason is that `e-mail` (without quotes) is not a valid column name and that `group` is a keyword. So the query won't parse. Both column names need to be enclosed in backticks so MySQL will actually treat them as column names:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, surname, nickname, `e-mail`, password, `group`, token) VALUES ...
```

You should definitely turn on error reporting because this would have probably revealed this error (plus several more in the script) already. Additionally, as someone already pointed out, your script is definitely vulnerable to SQL injection and you should care about it.